# opcua module in python

Tags: python, opc-ua

I currently have Python 2.7.15 installed, and I am trying to import the python opcua module. I am doing this specifically to access the Server method. So far, I have tried two approaches, both which gave the same error that follows.

**ImportError: No module named opcua**

First approach:

```
from opcua import Server
```

Second approach:

```
from __future__import opcua
```

Do I first need to install a separate package before I can use the opcua module?

Comment: `pip install opcua` https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua

Comment: `pip install asyncua` https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with :`pip install opcua` you will install the module you need, and you don't need **future** . And after, in your code:

```
from opcua import Client, ua
```

Client is the class por connection and take data from the server, and ua is the modules with some tools like conversion types and more.